# windows tablet development exists in phonegap or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, tablet

I want to know whether phonegap plugin supports windows tablet development or not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that right now phonegap does not support windows OS running on tablets.

There is an initial open source code developed by Intel to demo such capabilities, but it is "work in progress" and it doesn't seem to be "worked on" frequently.

Check this [post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/12/Windows-7-version-of-PhoneGapCordova) as well as the [project repository](https://github.com/otcshare/cordova-win7).